# unable to show and hide div inside loop based on click

Tags: angularjs

I have very simple code this is working properly my problem is i am unable to change like to unlike and unlike to like div

```
<div class="posts" ng-repeat="s in newsFeeds">
    {{s.message}}

    <div ng-if="s.likeStatus === 1">
           <div class="liked">
             <a ng-click="unlikePost(s.id,s.userid)">liked</a>
          </div>
    </div>
   <div ng-if="s.likeStatus === 0">
       <div class="like">
         <a ng-click="likePost(s.id, s.userid)">like</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My method

```
$scope.likePost = function (id, userid) {

        var data = 'id=' + id + "&userid=" + userid;
         console.log(data);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "like",
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function successCallback(rs, status, headers, config) {
             if (rs.data.st === 1) {
                console.log("liked");
                $scope.likeStatus = 0;
            } else if (rs.data.st === 0) {
                console.log("Sdfbb");
            }
        }, function errorCallback(data, status, header, config) {
            alert("Opps unable to connect to server");
        }
        );
    };
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON here, which is list retrieving from server?

Comment: why you are using single scope variable ?? imagine you have 10 news feeds .. how you will track its tracked or no ?... you need to add IsLiked inside the newFeed Object

Comment: is your `likePost()` function being called? In case it isn't, the main reason would be because `ng-if` creates a new child scope, therefore, from inside it, you need to use `$parent.likePost` to find it. That's bad practice though, use controllerAs

Comment: I have multiple posts in list.  i want to resolve this for all.

Comment: @xrcwrn I have multiple solutions I can provide you lets convert to chat then will post the most correct one that suits u

Comment: @HanyHabib I dont have any idea please guide me

Comment: Add your code in plunker and will update it for u now can you ?

Comment: ok will share line

Comment: i posted the answer for you here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172883/discussion-between-xrcwrn-and-hany-habib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments you need to have likeStatus with each item in newsFeed to be tracked correctly to do so you can do the following :

```
<div class="posts" ng-repeat="s in newsFeeds">
    {{s.message}}

    <div ng-if="s.likeStatus === 1">
           <div class="liked">
             <a ng-click="unlikePost(s)">liked</a>
          </div>
    </div>
   <div ng-if="s.likeStatus === 0">
       <div class="like">
         <a ng-click="likePost(s)">like</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and your controller like:

```
$scope.likePost = function (item) {

        var data = 'id=' + item.id + "&userid=" + item.userid;

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "like",
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function successCallback(rs, status, headers, config) {
             if (rs.data.st === 1) {

                item.likeStatus = 1;
            } else if (rs.data.st === 0) {
                console.log("error or something");
            }
        }, function errorCallback(data, status, header, config) {
            alert("Opps unable to connect to server");
        }
        );
    };
```

same you need to change in Unlike method to use the newsFeed Object. Like this you will be have track per each item  and one solid entity instead of multiple.

Also another advice to move the service call from the controller to angular service for better maintability.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work because $scope.likeStatus=0 at the response of your call is general. You can pass the $index variable at your function and then build an array with likeStatus like this:

1)Pass your $index parameter

```
<a ng-click="likePost(s.id, s.userid, $index)">like</a>
```

2)And in your function

```
$scope.likePost = function (id, userid,index) {

        var data = 'id=' + id + "&userid=" + userid;
         console.log(data);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "like",
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function successCallback(rs, status, headers, config) {
             if (rs.data.st === 1) {
                console.log("liked");
                $scope.likeStatus[index] = 0;
            } else if (rs.data.st === 0) {
                console.log("Sdfbb");
            }
        }, function errorCallback(data, status, header, config) {
            alert("Opps unable to connect to server");
        }
        );
    };
```

3)Change your ng-if

```
<div ng-if="likeStatus[$index] == 0">
```

Comment: @T.Sardelis why u seperated the likeStatus in seperate array ? .. i have a small idea that the likeStatus should be insinde the newsFeed item object to be easily tracked.. what do you think ?